# JQuery - $ is not defined with Yeoman

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am starting a new web application with Yeoman, and i would like to know why i can not access to $ elements.
For example, i have this:

```
<ul id="collapse">
<li>asdas</li>
<ul id="collapse2">
    <li>sgdfg</li>
    <li>fdg</li>
    <li>dfg</li>
</ul>   
<li>asdasd</li>
<ul>
    <li>sgdfg</li>
    <li>fdg</li>
    <li>dfg</li>
</ul>
```

And i want to acces by id to the first ul:

```
var $collap = angular.element($('#collapse'));
var $collap = $('#collapse');
```

I think, i have well load the jquery lib, because yeoman do it for me, and i tryed this one:

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
    window.alert('si');
} else {
window.alert('no');
```

To know if jquery is load and it is load. i do not know what more i can try, i have read a lot about this kind of error but no one matches with mine.
Here is my index:

```
[...]
<!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
 <script>
   !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
   (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
   r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
   }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script 
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

This is what i get every time i try something new: '$' is not defined.
If anyone could help me i would be very grateful.

I have also tryed with:

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And it still does not work.

Comment: You're including the jQuery twice, once from CDN and other from bower components. Remove one and it should work.

Comment: oh thanks that was a desperate attempt, i have tryed with only 1 of them and still no work. i will change the question anyway thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things that you have to take care in your code.

First your are loading jQuery twice. Please load jQuery only once.

Second if your jQuery is loading asynchronously, this sometime create problem. It  means your code is getting called first before jquery load. This is not correct. Please make sure your jQuery load before other calling methods.

Third, if you are using angular then use dependency injection feature to resolve '$' dependency in angular service or controller.

Comment: ok the first one is solved.
2º i have wrapped my function by   window.onload = function()   i have read it is the correct way. 
3º how can i inject jquery? i have problem with that, i am starting now with angularjs and i am a bit lost

Comment: Check the answer here to inject jQuery [link] (http://www.totaldotnet.com/sub/add-jquery-dependency-to-angular-js-controller)

Comment: after all the morning working on it, you have saved me, thanks you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy that i can able to help.